# How to remove element in dictionary by using filter in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, filter

I have a dictionary that looks like this, I want to remove *all elements that contain stock = 0.

```
    variations =     {
    "64FB5468-96E9-41A4-A779-3FB57FF1296B" =         {
        price = 10;
        sku = 123456;
        stock = 1;
        volume = 1L;
    };
    "A5EDB714-3D39-42DA-9A5C-2392D39C3AEB" =         {
        price = 20;
        sku = 254648;
        stock = 0;
        volume = 2L;
    };
    "BCA98B51-B058-4ABE-9010-54B080B819FB" =         {
        price = 30;
        sku = 284964;
        stock = 0;
        volume = 3L;
    };
};
```

I used the code below, however, it returns found nil while unwrapping error. How to properly remove the dictionary that has 0 stock inside variations dictionary? kSTOCK is a constant for string "stock"

```
    let filterAllItems = self.allItems.filter({(($0.variations as AnyObject)[$0] as! [String:Any])[kSTOCK] as! Int > 0})
```

Comment: Your question is ambiguous: Do you want to remove one element or all elements which match the condition? And what type is that object, a  struct (because of `.variations`) or a dictionary? And what is the declared type of the dictionaries with the UUID keys: `[String:Int]` or `[String:Any]`

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion. I want to remove all elements that match the condition. In this case, there should just be one dictionary left inside variations dictionary. The dictionaries with the UUID keys are of type  [String:Any].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `allItems` is a `[String:Any]` dictionary make a (mutable) copy of `variations`, filter the objects, remove the values of the found keys and reassign the dictionary to `allItems`

```
if var variations = allItems["variations"] as? [String:[String:Any]] {
    let allItemsWithStock0 = variations.filter({($0.value["stock"] as? Int) == 0})
    for (key, _) in allItemsWithStock0 {
        variations.removeValue(forKey: key)
    }
    allItems["variations"] = variations
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public extension Dictionary {
    @inlinable public mutating func removeIf(condition: (Self.Element) -> Bool) {
        for (key, _) in filter(condition) { removeValue(forKey: key) }
    }
}
```